# When does the judging take place?

Tags: support, status-completed, contest

I am planning to work some more on my apps tomorrow and get some last minute changes implemented. However, I notice that:

> The API Contest winners will be picked the first week of August.

...which includes tomorrow.

Will I be safe working on it tomorrow, or should I be worried about you guys looking over my app while its undergoing maintenance?

Comment: yes. ambiguous dates are of little value to the intended audience. When is the cutoff for an app or library to be considered?

Comment: If we have any influence, allow me to request the StackExchange Pantheon take a lazy Sunday.  Eat ambrosia, lounge on a cloud, and allow us to put a shine on our stuff one last day :)

Comment: @Dave: couldn't have put it better myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your [app] isn't available at the end of the day tomorrow, its not getting considered.

The cutoff is the start of "the first week of August," so you have (roughly) until its August 1st or later across the entire Earth.

Comment: Do you guys know what day of the week you're judging the apps though?

Comment: @George - No.  How long it takes for us to reach a consensus (and properly vet all the [app]s) is too hard to predict.  We've given you a week in which it will happen, it won't get any more precise.

Comment: @Kevin: Completely NOT out of curiosity: if an app makes it onto the apps tab *during* Judgement Week, will it be considered, or did it have to make it there prior to Aug 1?

Comment: Do app updates count? What if I update my app during this week (today), will the update be considered?

Comment: @dave - i don't think that visibility on the apps tab is a criteria. it has been stated that efforts of merit will be considered regardless of popularity, which is the criteria for visibility on the apps tab.

Comment: @code where have you read "regardless of popularity"?

Comment: @system - there is a conversation with joel or jeff somewhere in here that talks about it. check joel's or jeff's activity and you will find it.

Comment: @system - or maybe it was robert. i don't remember and can't seem to find it. It may have been on the blog or on meta. in any case, visibility on apps tab was specifically excluded as a case for exclusion from consideration.

Comment: @systempuntoout: it states the judging criteria on Jeff's original blog post: "The entire Stack Overflow, Inc team will ultimately decide the winners based on **order of awesomeness** " It says they'll look at the votes, but it doesn't have to be the "winner" in terms of votes.

Comment: @code: the rules clearly state: "Only applications and libraries/wrappers listed on the apps tab of stackapps.com are eligible for consideration."  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-contest/

Comment: @dave - yeah, yeah, rules schmules. codeka found the conversation i alluded to.

Comment: @Dave: yes, your app/lib needs to be *listed* on the app tab, but the judging criteria is not related to your *position* on there. You could be #100 and still win if the judges believe your app/library is the most "awesome".

Answer (score 2):

[6 - 8 weeks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

[source of metrics](http://www.cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like **the judging's done!**

Here's the current site-wide status/notification bar message:

> API contest results have been decided, results to be published tomorrow.

---

**UPDATE:** We just **passed midnight UTC time!** If that notice was based on the same timezone that the whole Stack Exchange network uses, we should expect the results **within the next 24 hours.**

Comment: So much for getting sleep tonight!

Comment: Haha, I don't really know when "tomorrow" is to be honest. It's already lunchtime friday for me. That probably means the middle of the night. Not that I'm holding by breath, others have done far more outstanding apps than me ;)

Comment: @Far: ...and me. And it's Thursday evening where I am.

Comment: Thursday evening here as well and I'm waiting with bated breath to discover how the StackExchange Pantheon defines "awesomeness."  I give my app(s) 5% chance of being in the top 3 (but I'll take it!) :)

Comment: If the winners are already decided why are they torturing us with this wait until "tomorrow"? Especially when we don't know what "tomorrow" means!!

Comment: @felix, it takes some time to draft a blog post i guess.

Comment: @felix refer to my comment on the other thread about the whole "tomorrow" thing.  In case you don't want to go look, I'll say it again.   Tomorrow is tomorrow, then when it's tomorrow it's really today, so it'll be released tomorrow, then when it's tomorrow, it's really today, so it'll be released tomorrow... you catch my drift?